# happy number algo question solution not working

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

trying to figure out this coding problem:

Write an algorithm to determine if a number n is "happy".

A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

Return True if n is a happy number, and False if not.

I've done some work but I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Would appreciate some pointers. Thanks!

```
function isHappy(numba1){
    let sum = 0;
    numba = numba1.toString().split('')
    let numbaArr = numba.map(y => parseInt(y))
    for (var x = 0; x< numbaArr.length; x++){
            sum += numbaArr[x] ** 2
    }
    if (sum > 1){
        isHappy(sum)
    }
    else if (sum === 1){
        return true
    }
    else if (sum <= 0){
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to check if `numba1 === 1` before anything else.  Otherwise you're in an infinite loop

Comment: Also the nested `isHappy(sum)` doesn't use the return true/false at all

Comment: @Taplar can u explain why this ends up in an infinite loop? say numba1 is 19 for example. at some point the sum is going to be one (which means it should return true according to the second else if statement). but for some reason after that it reverts to undefined

Comment: I was an infinite loop before you edited the question.  The original code did not have the `if (sum > 1)` around the `isHappy(sum)` call.

Comment: @Taplar yea I edited it but still not sure why this doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems I see with your answer, one small and one large.

- Small: The value of the recursive call is not being returned. This:

  ```js
  if (sum > 1){
      isHappy(sum)
  }
  ```

  should be

  ```js
  if (sum > 1){
      return isHappy(sum)
  }
  ```
- Large: you are not doing the essential work of checking whether we're cycling over the same values.  For instance in testing `15`, we get these values

  ```
  15, 26, 40, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, 16
              ^^                              ^^
  ```

  and we can quit because we've seen `16` twice.  `15` is not happy.  But for `44` we get

  ```
  44, 32, 13, 10, 1
  ```

  and we hit `1` without cycling, so `44` is a happy number.

  Your code needs to keep track of the values it's seen so far.

Here's one recursive approach:

```js
const digitsSquareSum = (n) => 
  String (n) .split ('') .map (n => n * n) .reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)

const _isHappy = (n, seen) =>
  n == 1
    ? true
  : seen .has (n) 
    ? false
  : _isHappy (digitsSquareSum (n), seen .add (n))

const isHappy = (n) => 
  _isHappy(n, new Set())

// display the happy numbers among the first 100 positive integers
console .log (Array .from ({length: 100}, (_, i) => i + 1) .filter (isHappy) .join(', '))
```

We use a helper function to calculate the sum of the squares of the digits.  This simply makes the main function cleaner.  The main function, `_isHappy` is an internal, private function, not to be exposed to the users.  It is recursive and maintains a `Set` of the values we've already seen.  If our number is `1`, we return `true`.  If our number is in the set of values we've already seen, we return `false`.  Otherwise, we add it to the already seen set, calculate the next test case by calling our helper, and call `_isHappy` with those.

Our public function simply calls this main function, creating the initial empty `Set` of seen values, and passing that along with the number to test.

In our demo, we use `Array .from ({length: 100}, (_, i) => i + 1)`, which is one of several compact ways of creating an array of integers from `1` to `100`.  In practice, I would abstract this into a `range` function that takes `lo` and `hi` values and creates an array of integers in between them, but that's outside the point of this answer.

We do not have to use this breakdown of an internal recursive function with two parameters and a public function with one.  We could use a default parameter like this:

```js
const isHappy = (n, seen = new Set()) =>
  console .log({n, seen}) ||
  n == 1
    ? true
  : seen .has (n) 
    ? false
  : isHappy (digitsSquareSum (n), seen .add (n))
```

But there are some potential problems with this.  For instance we could not call it like we did before:

```js
range(1, 100) .filter (isHappy)
```

because `filter` supplies additional parameters to its callback.  Not only does it supply the value but also the index and the whole array.  However `isHappy` thinks the second parameter is the `Set` of seen values; when it gets passed the index, things will fail.  We can do this instead:

```js
range(1, 100) .filter ((n) => isHappy (n))
```

But we will always have to take such cautions when writing this way.  I've gotten in the habit of doing this only for internal functions where I control how it's called.  And still once in a while it bites me.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a list of seen numbers and mod 10 to get the last digit then divide by 10 and floor to shift digits:

```js
function sumSquares(num) {
    let sum = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        sum += (num % 10) ** 2;
        num = Math.floor(num / 10);
    }
    return sum;
}

function isHappy(num) {
    const seen = new Set();
    while (num != 1 && !seen.has(num)) {
        seen.add(num);
        num = sumSquares(num);
    }
    return num == 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't return the result of the recursive call nor do you check for cycles.